# What would happen if I add the same NSManagedObject in to-many relationship few times?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data

I need to insert few NSManagedObject subclass instances (**Object B**) in the to-many relationship of the **Object A**, but I don't know if these **Objects B** is already exist in **Object A** relationship. What would happen if I will insert them? Would they be inserted twice, or Core Data wouldn't do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the to-many relationship is accessed as a `NSSet`, only unique objects will be added (this is a feature of NSSet's) so you don't need to worry about checking to see if it is already there first.

To quote the documentation for `NSSet`:

> NSSet declares the programmatic interface for static sets of distinct objects.

and from the `NSMutableSet` documentation:

> **addObject:**
>
> Adds a given object to the set, if it is not already a member.
>
> ```
> - (void)addObject:(id)object
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *object*
>
> The object to add to the set.